# Android app is lagging on mobile devices

Tags: android, lag

I have made an android app having one activity with a drawer layout.

The app runs slow on my device, showing a lag when sliding the drawer.

I don't know how to reduce this lag.

Here's my main layout code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

         <include 
             android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
             layout="@layout/toolbar" />

         <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#BBBB00"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/drawer_logo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_margin="0px" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            android:background="#BBBB00" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe add Android tag

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter with the drawer?  If so, post that code. Also, post your activity code

Comment: the problem was solved. I had to reduce the resolution of the image used in this imagview. Thanks anyway.